# Testing tools for i18n application

Tags: localization, internationalization, globalization

Any suggestion for a tool to test internationalized/ localized application? The application's UI is through web interface. The localized strings are stored in xml files.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to test, but for a desktop application I'm working on some of the translatable strings are for use in menu's. These strings may contain keyboard shortcuts, e.g.: "Open\tCtrl-O". We need to include the keyboard shortcut since Ctrl-O might need to be translated to some other keyboard shortcut in another language. However, some translators would (not on purpose of course) introduce bugs. For example, they would include a space between \t and Ctrl-O or they would translate the "Ctrl". Our solution was to create a small number of unit tests and run these on every English string-translated string combination for every language. So that's a lot of tests (over 50000 in our case) but they run very fast (10 seconds or so) since it's mostly just string comparisons.

We test for things like:

- No spaces between \t and the keyboard shortcut,
- If there is a keyboard shortcut in the English string, there should be one in the translation as well,
- If the English string has no line breaks, neither should the translation,
- If the English string ends with '...' (signalling a menu item that opens a dialog) the translation should end with '...' as well.

I hope this is still useful as you are talking about a web application and my experience is with a desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

One way to 'test' an i18n application is to make sure you are addressing all the locale specific behaviors and translated resources. This usually requires setting up a QA plan.

Among the steps you'll have to perform is making sure the formatting of currency, numbers, dates, times or other measurements are done properly, based on each locale. There is not specific tool that I know of to check for that.

Another aspect is to make sure all the user visible strings are indeed out of the code and in the resource bundles, whichever type that may be (from .properties to .po to .xml ... the choice is large). Some QA team set up a 'pseudo-localization' strategy, meaning a resource bundle is created with the original strings in it but with prefix and suffix 'special' characters, such as Japanese Hiragana's for instance. Then invoking the application with the pseudo locale shows all the strings with the prefix and suffix while allowing the developer to see what is missing (those strings without the hiragana's) and how the layout management is behaving (cropping text which it should not).

There are a number of tools to do that, like Globalyzer from Lingoport which deals with i18n in general and the pseudo localization is one part of it (in the menus, it's actually called "PseudoJudo"). It allows to grow the text by a given percentage, have only the prefix or only the suffix or both appended to the original string.

Hope that answers your question, at least partly.